# How to set Recyclerview to show only 4 tiles

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

So, ive implemented a RecyclerView which has 15 items, now what I want to do is to restrict the RecyclerView to 4 items when I click a button and vice versa, i'm not sure how to do that, this is what I have done, any inputs would be helpful

```
floatingButton.Click += delegate {
            if (clicked)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Has been clicked before", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                recyclerview_layoutmanger = new GridLayoutManager(this,, 2);
                myRecyclerview.SetLayoutManager(recyclerview_layoutmanger);
                recyclerview_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                clicked = false;
            }
            else {
                recyclerview_layoutmanger = new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
                Toast.MakeText(this, "Has not been clicked before", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                myRecyclerview.SetLayoutManager(recyclerview_layoutmanger);
                recyclerview_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
                clicked = true;
            }
        };
```

Adapter Class

```
  public class RecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public event EventHandler<int> ItemClick;

        private readonly List<MessageList> messages;

        public RecyclerAdapter(List<MessageList> messages)
        {
            this.messages = messages;
            NotifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {
            var movieViewHolder = (MessageViewHolder)holder;
            movieViewHolder.messageView.Text = messages[position].Message;
            movieViewHolder.dateView.Text = messages[position].messageDate;
            // movieViewHolder.MovieImageView.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.starwarslogo);
        }

        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            var layout = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.messages_list_layout, parent, false);

            return new MessageViewHolder(layout, OnItemClick);

        }

        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get { return messages.Count; }
        }

        void OnItemClick(int position)
        {
            if (ItemClick != null)
                ItemClick(this, position);
        }
    }

        /// <summary>
        /// Called after <c><see cref="M:Android.App.Activity.OnRestoreInstanceState(Android.OS.Bundle)" /></c>, <c><see cref="M:Android.App.Activity.OnRestart" /></c>, or
        /// <c><see cref="M:Android.App.Activity.OnPause" /></c>, for your activity to start interacting with the user.
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnResume()
    {
        var toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.DrawerLayout, this.AppToolbar, 0, 0);
        this.DrawerLayout.AddDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.SyncState();

        base.OnResume();
    }
```

But this just changes the layout to a side by side kinda thing

Comment: post your adapter class here

Comment: added,please check

Comment: replace `return messages.Count; ` to `return 4;`

Comment: @Sunny,how can I do that after I set the adapter,i want that to be dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your RecyclerView is powered by your adapter.

The no of items it displays is equal to the `ItemCount` you give in your adapter.

You can change it by adding a public method in the adapter to change your dataset:

```
public void SetMessages(List<MessageList> newDataset) {
    messages = newDataset;
}
```

And you can use this method like this:

```
adapter.SetMessages(myMessages); // myMessages is a List<MessageList> containing 4 objects
recyclerView.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Edit:**

In your case to show only 4 items from a list of 15 items you can call `SetMessages` like this:

```
// oldList is your list containing 15 items
adapter.SetMessages(new List(oldList.GetRange(0, 4))); 
recyclerView.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: how do I make this dynamic though,like lets say I have 15 items added,and now I need to change it to a List<Messages> with 4 items or 5 etc,could you be more specific??

Comment: this didn't quite work out,but I was able to figure out from this,thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to limit your arraylist to size 4 then inflate it in recycler view rather than doing changes in recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in `getItemsCount()`

**Solution:**

```
class Adapter<ViewHolder> extends ...{
boolean userClicked=false;
//your other method

 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if(userClicked)
    return yourlist.size();
    else
    return yourlist.size()>4?4:yourlist.size();
}

public void setUserClicked( boolean userClicked){
        this.userClicked=userClicked;
        notifyDatasetChanged();
 }
}
```

Comment: the problem is i'm working on C#,which is new to me,Java I would have made it work somehow